# Responsive image on top of the background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make following. 
Background image that is responsive and has a certain theme. I want to add a flickering light effect on top of that background image. To do a flickering itself not an issue.
The background image is a street with a light pole on it. I want the light in the pole flicker.
**The problem:** When background image scales with window size the overlaying flicker image shifts allover and does not stay above pole bulb. 
How can i fix that?

Here is one of posts that shows hot to make image stick BUT its only stick to top.[div on top of responsive background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199542/div-on-top-of-responsive-background-image)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MWW</title>

<link href="_css/main-test.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="_script/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_script/animation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bgDiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background-color: black;    
}

.bgDiv {
    background-image:url(../_images/image_3.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;   
    background-size: cover; 
    background-color: black;
    height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Posting your current code would help a lot.

Comment: I can think of a workaround which is you don't use the background image as a background instead, just have 2 images 1 overlaying the other so when resize happens both images resizes the same

Comment: Yes Sir. I did try to make and image in the div but also stumbled in the same problem with everything scaling properly.

Comment: well code doesn't matter because its a mechanics of how it should work that what counts.

Comment: Have you thought about converting the image to a GIF, or Flash/HTML5 video?

Comment: Yes i did. I was thinking to build an actual animation and run as a background. But in this case the future plan of having some parts of the image that will become an action looks impossible.
For example: image has a door. i wan user to mouse over it and knocking sound will be played. on click user will trigger an image change.

Comment: It can definitely be done, but you might have to use an HTML5 canvas. Unfortunately, I don't know very much about this kind of interactivity - hopefully someone with more experience can help you!

Comment: I certainly hope so. I am thinking to make a gif and then maybe maparea tag to have onclick events. Not sure.